# Asp.net Method call after all events have finished

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.5

I have a check box on a page with a server side event that, when triggered, will go to the database to update a value. The check box also causes it's parent check box to become checked, and trigger it's event to update the database.

I was wondering if there was a way to say, after everything is done with their events, go to the database once, rather than going once for each check box.

Comment: Create a `Stored Procedure`? Use something like `Entity Framework` or `nHibernate`? There are many options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use jQuery or a client js framework that will allow you to select the parent/child checkboxes and fire a POSTBACK event manually, you can write you js conditions and fire the service call depending on the conditions you want to make, to fire that event you can use [__doPostBack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328923) and pass both checkboxes as parameters then in the single event you can have a condition to make the operation you want to do